# PostgreSQL position function returns all records

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 select substring(bla,position('PMR' in bla),10) from x
```

I understand that if substring is not found in the string, then the position function will return 0. In db2 I could write substring(bla,locate('PMR',bla),10).How can I acheive this in postgresSQL?

I want to display 10 charachers after PMR.
Example:

```
abcdefgPMR213141565
abcdefgdaaaaaPMR213141563

Result:
213141565
213141563
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `len` of search string to the `postion` of string to get the result. Try this.

```
select substring('abcdefgPMR213141565',
                 position('PMR' in 'abcdefgPMR213141565')+char_length('PMR'),10)
```

**Result:** `213141565`

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b2ed6/3)**

**Update:** to handle when search string is not found

```
select substring(a,
                 position('PMR' in a)+ 
                case when  position('PMR' in a) =0 then 0 
                 else char_length('PMR') end ,10)  
from x
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4605/6)**